# Partial Postback request does not hit server

Tags: asp.net, telerik, partial-postback

This issue has started annoying me and I am not able to phrase a right question on google. Let me know if you think the mentioned problem is still not clear.

**Scenario:**

I have a master page which has one `LinkButton` named "Create" inside an UpdatePanel. FYI I also have RadAjaxManager in the content page. 
When the user clicks on this link button a partial postback is triggered. After some processing on the server, at the end of this request a Script is registered which Launches a new window with a different page. 
This new window can be closed by one button named 'Abort'.

**Problem:**

If I click on the LinkButton for four or five times everything works fine. But on next Click(on 6th or 7th click) the AjaxRequest is triggered but it does not reach the server at all. The Ajax Loading panel shows but the request does not hit the server and finally I get the following error.

`Error: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerTimeoutException: The server request timed out.`

I am not able to understand what exactly is going wrong. Really appreciate for any help or pointers that anyone can give.

**EDIT:**

Note: Fiddler also does not show any request sent to the erver.

**EDIT**

Some more information. The application I am working on IE8 compat view. When I used the profiling tool I got following calltree in. Not sure about this but I can see an abortPostback which was invoked. Now I am trying to figure out why was this invoked. If anyone can give me some insight on how the pagerequestmanager cycle works would be really good for me.

Following is the call tree if it helps.

```
Function
_onFormSubmit
assureControlState
append
indexOf
a
_getScrollPosition
_endPostBack
IsChildOf
OutputEncoder_EncodeHtml
_onDocumentClick
executeRequest
loadBdy
_initializeRequest
DomEvent
getElementById
_getPostBackSettings
encodeURIComponent
Object$getType
String
_isMainElementDescendant
isDescendant
_onTimeout
_getResponseHeader
_onPageRequestManagerEndRequest
Array.join
b
DomEvent
_doPostBack
String.toUpperCase
showLoadingPanels
displayLoadingElement
get_httpVerb
JScript - window script block
JScript - window script block
createErrorHTML
String.fromCharCode
_getWindow
Function$_validateParams
Function$_validateParameterCount
Math.min
Function$_validateParameter
Function$_validateParameterType
String.toLowerCase
String$startsWith
_isInstanceOfType
String.substr
String.toString
Function.call
JScript - window script block
Function.apply
_onMouseOut
_getContextMenuElement
JScript - window script block
JScript - window script block
close
get_openedItem
onfocus
_Application$findComponent
hide
_hide
JScript - window script block
get_originalText
get_element
get_dropDownElement
JScript - window script block
_clearTimer
emptyMethod
completed
_get_eventHandlerList
getHandler
_getEvent
clone
Array
_get_eventHandlerList
JScript - window script block
_onFormSubmitCompleted
_handleAsyncRedirect
Error
get_timedOut
get_webRequest
remove_completed
removeHandler
remove
isNaN
Array.splice
_onFormSubmitCompleted
_createPageRequestManagerTimeoutError
create
popStackFrame
_get_eventHandlerList
EndRequestEventArgs
initializeBase
resolveInheritance
EventArgs
endRequestHandler
get_dataItems
_serializeState
_endRequest
remove_endRequest
hideLoadingPanels
hide
format
_toFormattedString
String.indexOf
String.slice
String.charAt
String.substring
parseInt
Date
Date.valueOf
AjaxLoadingPanelEventArgs
JScript - window script block
raiseEvent
get_events
get_cancelNativeDisplay
get_animationDuration
get_response
get_aborted
RadAjaxRequestEventArgs
CancelEventArgs
String.replace
fireEvent
get_errorHandled
_getWindow
startsWith
_onFormElementClick
_onFormElementActive
contains
_createPostBackSettings
_matchesParentIDInList
JScript - window script block
_hideOnBodyClick
JScript - window script block
_uniqueIDToClientID
StringBuilder
WebRequest
encodeURI
set_url
get_headers
set_timeout
createDelegate
add_completed
EventHandlerList
addHandler
enqueue
toString
set_body
InitializeRequestEventArgs
_initializeRequest
get_postBackElement
_initializeRequest
callBaseMethod
getBaseMethod
getBaseType
getInstance
get_isInAsyncPostBack
String.split
get_cancel
_attachRequestHandlers
get_id
add_endRequest
get_request
Array.reverse
get_body
String.lastIndexOf
_showLoadingPanelsForGivenElement
get_ajaxSettings
findComponent
show
hideUpdatedElement
_showLoadingPanelsForElementsInRequestQueue
_onPageRequestManagerBeginRequest
beginRequestHandler
_validPosition
abortPostBack
BeginRequestEventArgs
_cancelPendingCallbacks
invoke
executeRequest
get_executor
eval
eval code
XMLHttpExecutor
WebRequestExecutor
set_executor
_set_webRequest
NetworkRequestEventArgs
getResolvedUrl
_resolveUrl
_onReadyStateChange
get_timeout
JScript - window script block
JScript - window script block
JScript - window script block
JScript - window script block
JScript - window script block
JScript - window script block
JScript - window script block
OutputEncoder
JScript - window script block
onload
createErrorInfo
String.charCodeAt
getShortURL
extractAllAfterChar
extractUpToChar
stripPath
OutputEncoder_EncodeXml
syncListViewControlState
```

**EDIT**
This does not stop annoying me. What I did, is removed all the ajax settings and let link do a complete postback.

Fun part is that the problem that I mentioned is not only with Ajax postback, but same thing happens on on a full post back. If I click the link 5 times the sixth time the request never levaes from the client machine( tracked using fiddler) and finally the browser crashes with the standard **"Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage"** message

Comment: The abortPostBack function is called inside the PageRequestManager$_onFormSubmit function. I suggest you to debug this method when the problem occurs.

Comment: How do I debug the _onFormSubmit function? The problem is that I dont have any control over these function. On top of that I have telerik ajaxmanager in the page which downloads lot for scripts by itself.

Comment: Open Developer Tools on Chrome. Go To the Sources Tab. Ctrl + Shift + F to search in all files. Search for _onFormSubmit, go the the function definition and put a breakpoint. While debuging you'll see what's causing the postback to be aborted. You could also compare to the postbacks that do work and see what is the difference and why it exists.

Comment: If the compatibility view puts the browser in quirks mode (see the document mode dropdown), weird stuff may happen, as this is something inbetween IE5 and IE6...Try adding an X-UA Compatible meta tag to put the browser in standards mode, make sure you have a valid doctype (XHTML 1.0 transiitonal is easiest to satisfy) and your markup is valid.
Also, make sure you do not nest AJAX settings with the UpdatePanel you already have in place.

Comment: The docttype is XHTML 1.0 Transitional. The document mode is IE7Standards. I did not get the last point your mentioned about nesting Ajax Settings with the UpdatePanel. Can you elaborate a bit?

Comment: Are you by chance using clientIdmode="static" ?